# PHP Form keep input values together to create JSON list

Tags: php, html, json, forms

I have a JSON list with conditions(items) and a color associated to every condition.  I'm building a form to try to update the conditions, then return to the JSON format.

Example:

```
<?php
?>    
$JSON_list = {
        "FULL":"green",
        "Half-Full":"amber",
        "Quarter-Full":"amber",
        "Empty":"red"
        }
```

I json_decode() this list to turn it into a php array. Then iterate through it and display the values as inputs which can be edited.

```
<form action="updatedata.php" method="post">
<?php
foreach($JSON_list as $condition) {
        foreach($condition as $item => $color){
?>
            <input type="text" name="item[]" value="<?=$item;?>">
            <select name="color[]">
                <option selected="selected"><?=$color;?></option>
                <option>green</option>
                <option>amber</option>
                <option>red</option>
            </select>
            <br>
<?php
        };
    };
};

?>    
<input type="submit" value="Submit Conditions"> 
</form>
```

On submission of the form, the "items" & "colors" are stored in 2 different arrays separate from each other. I iterate through each of these arrays to obtain the new values, and then concatenate them into a JSON list again.

updatedata.php:

```
<?php
    $num = count($_POST['item']);
    
    $i = 1; 
    $subs = [];
    foreach($_POST["item"] as $item){
            $subs["item".$i] = $item;  
            $i++;
    };
    $c = 1;
    foreach($_POST["color"] as $item){
        $subs["color".$c] = $item;
        $c++;
    };
    
    $submit_string = "";
    $a = 1;
    $comma = ",";
    for($x = 0; $x < $num; $x++){
        if($a == $num){
            $comma = "";
        };
        $submit_string .= "\"".$subs["item".$a]."\":"."\"".$subs["color".$a]."\"".$comma;
        $a++;
    };

    echo "{" . $submit_string . "}";
    

    //Prints the JSON string "FULL":"green","Half-Full":"amber","Quarter-Full":"amber","Empty":"red"
    
    ?>
```

My problem occurs when the "item" input is submitted with nothing, if an item has a value of "" then I don't want this entry in the JSON list.  I need to delete this entry, but also the "color" associated to that item.

Is there a way to link the "items" & "numbers" from the form so I can delete both entries??

Answer (score 0):

I think there is maybe a bit more to your code you are not showing us, for example with the given structure of `$JSON_list` the 2 nested `foreach` loops you have to generate the HTML would not work.  Here's what I did to get your code working:

1. `$JSON_list` needs quotes and a trailing semi-colon:

   ```
   $JSON_list = '{
       "FULL":"green",
       "Half-Full":"amber",
       "Quarter-Full":"amber",
       "Empty":"red"
   }';
   ```
2. Convert it to an array:

   ```
   $array = json_decode($JSON_list, true);
   ```
3. Generate the HTML:

   ```
   <?php foreach ($array as $item => $color) { ?>
       <input type="text" name="item[]" value="<?php echo $item; ?>">
       <select name="color[]">
           <option selected="selected"><?php echo $color; ?></option>
           <option>green</option>
           <option>amber</option>
           <option>red</option>
       </select>
       <br>
   <?php } ?>
   ```

Next, if you dump out what you're getting back from a form submission, it gives you an idea of how to process it.  Here's the output of `print_r($_POST);` after the form was submitted with the "HALF-FULL" text input blank:

```
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => FULL
            [1] => 
            [2] => Quarter-Full
            [3] => Empty
        )

    [color] => Array
        (
            [0] => green
            [1] => amber
            [2] => amber
            [3] => red
        )
)
```

So now the relation between the 2 arrays is clear, and you can see we can use the array keys to map the elements of one to the other.

```
// We'll store our results in this new array
$submitted = [];

// Iterate over the first array elements
foreach ($_POST['item'] as $key => $value) {

    // We only want to include item/colors that were non-blank,
    // so check if we got an item here
    if ($value) {
        // OK it wasn't blank, so let's save the result, using
        // the corresponding element from the color array
        $submitted[$value] = $_POST['color'][$key];
    }
}

// Now we have an array of our submitted data
// print_r($submitted);
// Array
// (
//     [FULL] => green
//     [Quarter-Full] => amber
//     [Empty] => red
// )
// You should never try to construct a JSON string manually, just
// let PHP do it for you:
$newList = json_encode($submitted);

// echo $newList;
// {"FULL":"green","Quarter-Full":"amber","Empty":"red"}
```

Comment: That works a treat!! Really appreciate the time taken to answer the question. Life saver!